# Directories automatically initializing with other's Git remotes

Tags: git, github, branch, version

I started up a new project and went to add the new remote after creating it on GitHub.  To my surprise, it had the origin of another project already.  I deleted those remotes, added the correct ones, and pushed.  And now when I go to the master branch on GitHub, it shows the source for three other projects.  Further, when I do a git status, I see nearly all my project folders(where I keep most of the project that I work on) under Untracked files.  Finally, it also shows changes not staged for commit for both the correct project and one other project.  Any ideas on why this could be happening?